# MOSFET TO-220 heat sink pad is electrically connected to drain. Can I solder wire or trace directly onto heat pad, instead of drain pin?

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, power-electronics, heatsink, bridge-rectifier

I have a board-layout where a lot of things would be easier if I could solder to the metal-pad of the TO-220 N-channel MOSFET, instead of the drain pin.

Apart from: "Metal pad was intended for heat-sink attachment, and bla bla",
**why is this a bad idea?**

**Or is it viable to do something like this?**

EMI - noise issues?

Image for illustration of MOSFET:
[image: mosfet]

Well, it's in the power stage of an ESK. The heat-sink-pads are convenient places to attach three thick output wires that happen to be attached to the drains of the low-side mosfets.
[image]

MOSFETs are attached on the bottom side of board, and the idea is to solder onto the MOSFET (in green). Can it be done? Should it be done?
[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Try explaining why you would want to do this.

Comment: Added a picture. Is there anything internally inside the mosfet that doesn't allow this to be a viable way to go? Is the idea just plain stupid?

Comment: From the pure electronics assembly perspective, don't solder anything there. End the wire in a ring ferrule, then attach that one to the TO220 by screw+nut or a rivet. How to do that in the best way depends on if you need to use a heatsink or not.

Comment: OK, so I CAN attach electrically to the heat-metal-pad (and leave the drain pin unattached), but just not by solder. It should be by screw+nut. Right?

Comment: There's nothing electrically wrong with it, but if you intend the part to be heatsinked, if you solder to the tab you'll probably ruin the thermal conductivity to the sink.  It's also terrible from a manufacturing standpoint.

Comment: How will you heatsink them?

Comment: @JohnD If you solder the tab to the heatsink, that will probably get you better thermal conductivity than thermal grease.

Comment: @Hearth I was thinking about soldering before mounting to the heat sink, and if any solder got on the interface side of the package it might not lie flat.  Soldering TO the heat sink might be OK but would be pretty difficult (not impossible, but hard).

Answer (score 1):

Yes but.

To clarify -- at least as far as I know -- you can safely assume TO-220 tab is always connected to the middle pin, unless otherwise indicated.

Some devices are connected this way intentionally, e.g. D2PAK which resembles TO-220 but has a minimal length tab, and leads formed so that the part lays flat on the PCB for SMT soldering.

TO-220 can be used this way, but it's not a good idea:

[image: Surface mounted TO-220] 
(A surface mounted TO-220 device. Source: my website)

- Random TO-220s may not have solderable plating.  Notice the poor wetting in the above photo; this STP70N10F4 has a nickel-plated tab, which is solderable only with great difficulty.  (The datasheet makes no mention of tab plating; assuming it's always a nice solderable tin plating may get you in trouble.)
- The tab wastes extra space that might be better spent on, say, nearby bypass capacitors, or just putting in more transistors for lower R<sub>ds(on)</sub>.
- The tab is there for heatsinking; you can't very well solder a wire to it while also bolting it to a heatsink.  Not for any kind of manufacturing process.

When the tab is used, in commercial designs, it might be secured with a bolt and star washer, to ensure electrical contact.  Thermal grease, and no insulator, would be used to ensure thermal conduction to the heatsink, which would then serve as the common terminal (for everything bolted to it in this way).  This is sometimes used in UPSs (uninterruptible power supplies), where a bolted connection is typical (currents over 30A are common, using thick wires with crimped lugs), and the output transformer connections can simply be bolted to the heatsinks.

The major downside to this connection is, at least for single devices (as shown in your diagram), the loop inductance is proportional to the length of the wiring.  Excessive inductance causes high power dissipation or outright destruction in power switching circuitry.  "Excessive" might be anywhere from 1µH down to merely a few nH, depending on the circuit.  A single round wire of some inches length, will have no less than 50nH inductance, making this a concern for some circuits.

Typically, power switching circuits are made on a PCB, where flat and wide connections can be made, keeping inductance very low (the component leads themselves dominate), and the tab is used only for heatsinking.  The leads may seem small (with TO-220AB leads having around 0.5 x 0.8 mm rectangular section), but they are also short, and can easily handle 50A or so.  (Datasheets often give "package" ratings, distinct from what the device within is ultimately capable of -- there are literally chips so powerful, they can't be fully utilized because the package isn't thick enough to handle it!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment here.

Comment: 6 years ago I replaced the mechanical regulation from a water boiler in hurry. I etched a little PCB (47x31mm) on one side was the Op-Amp and on the other side the tab of the MOC + TRIAC. He is powering a 1500W (@230V => 6.5A) heater and I am sure this get a bit hot (6.5A*1.5V=9.8 Watt). It is in a little Aluminium housing, but has no direct contact to it, because it need some insulation distance. With only 2.7x3.1cm = 8.4cm² copper area to spread the heat over the PCB it is working pretty good.